# N-th derivative of a product in binomial expansion?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, binomial-theorem

I believe that the following is true:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}f^{(n-m)}(x)g^{(m)}(x)$$

The rational part of the summation is binomial expansion constants and $f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)$

I have tested it for some values of $n$ where $f$ and $g$ are either polynomials or exponential functions and it appears to hold true.

The question is whether or not the above is true with a proof.

For those who concern, $n$ may or may not be a positive integer or even an integer at all because I wish to use this in Fractional Calculus allowing $n\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: How do you definie $a!$ if $a < 0$?

Comment: @Bib-lost Well, its harder to write it out as $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\dots(n-n)\dots$, but they are equivalent.

Comment: So how do you definie $n!$ if $n < 0$? What is (-2)! for example?

Comment: @Bib-lost Well, you'd never have to worry about that because $n-n=0$, which occurs if $n$ is a positive integer.  Just know that $|(-2)!|=\infty$ so that the denominator is infinity and the whole term becomes $0$.

Comment: In any case, if the terms in the series all become zero after the $n$th term, it would be cleaner (in my opinion) to just write $\sum_{i=1}^n$, as suggested by the answers bellow. Now you're making it look like a convergent series, instead of just a finite sum.

Comment: @Bib-lost Well, it obviously depends on what $n$ actually is, which most would assume to be an integer.  For my uses however, I am going to use it for non integer values for something related to Fractional Calculus, thus it won't be a finite summation for me.

Comment: Hmm, that does make your question considerably more difficult. Perhaps this is something you should mention in the question itself, as both answers (and I too) supposed $n$ to be a positive integer in your question.

Comment: just curious: how would you define the factorial of a non-integer?

Comment: @user190080 You would probably use the Gamma function.

Comment: @user190080 Or google calculator if you really want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a famous formula about the Nth-derivative of a product,
it's from Leibniz (so says my textbook at least).
It can be proved by induction without any obstacles.

It's just that the sum is finite.

See also: [General Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)

Answer (score 1):

This is the General Leibniz rule. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule